# How to get accounts data from solana snapshot file?

Tags: rust, snapshot

I need to get accounts information at the given snapshot. For that I untarred the snapshot archive and read account files from the extracted folder. I am not sure how to deserialize the data that is read from the files in the `accounts` folder. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

To read the account data you can use the `solana-ledger-tool` which comes with the [Solana Tool Suite](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools). You will also need the genesis file for the cluster your snapshot belongs to. These are the steps:

- Create a new folder that will hold your data: `mkdir solana-ledger && cd solana-ledger`
- Download the genesis for your cluster. You can get an archive of it from the RPC node by appending `genesis.tar.bz2` to it's address.
  For example, this is the Devnet genesis: `wget https://api.devnet.solana.com/genesis.tar.bz2`
- Unarchive the downloaded genesis into `solana-ledger`
- Create a new dir inside `solana-ledger`: `mkdir snapshots && cd snapshots`
- Copy your snapshot (**archived**) into this new folder
- This is how your folder structure should look right now:

```
~/solana-ledger$ tree
.
├── genesis.bin
├── genesis.tar.bz2
├── rocksdb
│   ├── 000003.log
│   ├── CURRENT
│   ├── IDENTITY
│   ├── LOCK
│   ├── LOG
│   ├── MANIFEST-000004
│   ├── OPTIONS-000024
│   └── OPTIONS-000026
└── snapshots
    └── snapshot-217675280-rW2GDuPopowN23ACP2i3EeizQiRW8UWszyxu2XHFZSE.tar.zst
```

- Next run the `solana-ledger-tool` command to get the accounts data:
  `solana-ledger-tool --ledger ~/solana-ledger --snapshot-archive-path ~/solana-ledger/snapshots accounts`

  (I got this message `Blockstore is incompatible with current software and requires updates`, so I had to add `--force-update-to-open` in the command to get it to work)
- It can take a while, depending on the size of the snapshot, but eventually it will output data. This is a sample of the output I got:

  ```
  1STjdgBeAtiRN6ZkTMneBfDVjoJ4kViziSkNqDjj6Cz:
    balance: 0.00203928 SOL
    owner: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA'
    executable: false
    slot: 217388445
    rent_epoch: 0
    data_len: 165
    data: '4bzlBnlO0XycxhPz4mZaR/aRneK5U45RfxB1t5Q5fJASNzh/t2GGxcXenziQ5gais7TWz6i+gjckcGAilrub3QAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
  ```

Notice that the data held by the account is base64 encoded. You can decode it into hex bytes with a tool [like this](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex) and it will output the same as if you ran `solana account %AccountPubkey%` on the live blockchain.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I need to get those accounts in rust code. Can you give me some advice on that?

Comment: If you want it in Rust code, you can do what the core devs do: hack `solana-ledger-tool`! https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/37887d487ce9b87297d9a20dd07a89adf4c66cd5/ledger-tool/src/main.rs#L3253-L3347 has the code doing `accounts`, so you can just add your code there, build your own ledger tool, and run that

Comment: Where do I get the rocksdb stuff from? I am able to download the snapshot and the genisis. (Also hopefully looking to acquire this without running an entire validator)