# Node synchronization issues

Tags: validator, node, installation

I am currently running a Solana validator, but I've noticed that the ledger folder is increasing in size while the accounts folder remains at 28kb. Am I synchronizing incorrectly? I followed the instructions at https://chainstack.com/how-to-run-a-solana-node/ during the installation. My primary goal is to download the accounts data. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node downloads the blockchain data as a compressed file called a snapshot, after this file is downloaded and processed the node starts validating. This can take between 5 minutes to over an hour if you're on mainnet with a less powerful server.

You should check the logs to see for errors. I know it logs a lot of data, but filter by "ERROR" (all-caps) or "restart" to identify problems.

If you just want the account data, you can download the snapshot yourself with these options:

- for mainnet: https://gist.github.com/mybluelotus/2ff5e9fd901ec1cb59d8fa24f115b857
- if you want a non-mainnet snapshot [use this](https://github.com/c29r3/solana-snapshot-finder) and use the `-r` arg to specify a custom RPC
- alternatively, RPC nodes offer the snapshot at this path `/snapshot.tar.bz2`, so find a RPC url and append that path to it to download. Get a list of RPC nodes with [this method](https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getclusternodes) or by running `solana gossip` in the command line and use the `RPC Address` column.

If you decompress the snapshot you will get this directory structure which contains the accounts:

```
$ tree .
.
├── accounts
│   ├── 221707449.713259
│   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   └── 222140108.985850
├── snapshots
│   ├── 222140108
│   │   └── 222140108
│   └── status_cache
└── version
```

Not sure what you want to do with the account data, but [here is one way to read it](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/7430/5398).

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail.