# Get all accounts from ledger

Tags: account, account-data, ledger, snapshot

To obtain all account information from the ledger, I used the following command:

`solana-ledger-tool --ledger /mnt/ledger/ accounts`

However, only the following information is printed, and the account details are not displayed.

```
...
[2023-09-18T14:34:34.364665127Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 89246 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:34:34.365109091Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 89246 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:34:44.409021592Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 93029 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:34:44.409291247Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 93029 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:34:44.411266362Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 93029 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:34:44.411578059Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 93030 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:34:54.409383385Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 97981 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:34:54.409431968Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 97975 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:34:54.411663597Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 97978 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:34:54.411933131Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 97983 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:04.409448941Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 101551 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:04.409733886Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 101552 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:04.411732023Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 101555 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:04.412092752Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 101555 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:14.467686121Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 105100 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:14.468003718Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 105101 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:14.468074262Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 105101 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:14.468079552Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 105101 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:17.445390874Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 106094 entries total
[2023-09-18T14:35:17.445726882Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 106094 entries total
[2023-09-18T14:35:17.445746803Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 106094 entries total
[2023-09-18T14:35:17.445992676Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 106095 entries total
[2023-09-18T14:35:17.433830017Z INFO  solana_runtime::shared_buffer_reader] reading entire decompressed file took: 264962203 us, bytes: 151528720896, read_us: 264398656, waiting_for_buffer_us: 0, largest fetch: 18743296, error: Ok(0)
[2023-09-18T14:35:17.582178981Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_utils] snapshot untar took 265.3s
[2023-09-18T14:35:27.606527634Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 3539 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:27.606909854Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 3539 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:27.606962397Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 3539 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:27.606982278Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 3540 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:37.606588386Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 8101 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:37.607218380Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 8100 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:37.608326169Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 8099 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:37.608509249Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 8098 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:47.617182538Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 11526 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:47.617431451Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 11527 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:47.617457332Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 11526 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:47.617483714Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 11527 entries so far...
[2023-09-18T14:35:48.778470357Z INFO  solana_runtime::shared_buffer_reader] reading entire decompressed file took: 31195530 us, bytes: 18359178240, read_us: 31151056, waiting_for_buffer_us: 0, largest fetch: 11272192, error: Ok(0)
[2023-09-18T14:35:48.797443581Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 11977 entries total
[2023-09-18T14:35:48.798492267Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 11976 entries total
[2023-09-18T14:35:48.800235680Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 11977 entries total
[2023-09-18T14:35:48.801235024Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] unpacked 11976 entries total
[2023-09-18T14:35:48.830917530Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_utils] incremental snapshot untar took 31.2s
[2023-09-18T14:35:48.980036126Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_utils] snapshot version: 1.2.0
[2023-09-18T14:35:48.980157572Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_utils] snapshot version: 1.2.0
[2023-09-18T14:35:48.980183134Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_utils] Loading bank from full snapshot /mnt/ledger/snapshot.ledger-tool/tmp-snapshot-archive-9nH7oc/snapshots/218270984/218270984 and incremental snapshot Some("/mnt/ledger/snapshot.ledger-tool/tmp-snapshot-archive-YsZcCY/snapshots/218319933/218319933")
[2023-09-18T14:36:21.450611236Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] metrics disabled: SOLANA_METRICS_CONFIG: environment variable not found
[2023-09-18T14:36:21.450931260Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_index estimate_mem_bytes=0i flush_should_evict_us=0i count_in_mem=0i count=0i bg_waiting_percent=99.60753631591797 bg_throttling_wait_percent=78.86961364746094 held_in_mem_slot_list_len=0i held_in_mem_slot_list_cached=0i min_in_bin_mem=0i max_in_bin_mem=0i count_from_bins_mem=0i median_from_bins_mem=0i min_in_bin_disk=0i max_in_bin_disk=0i count_from_bins_disk=0i median_from_bins_disk=0i gets_from_mem=0i get_mem_us=0i gets_missing=0i get_missing_us=0i entries_from_mem=0i entry_mem_us=0i load_disk_found_count=0i load_disk_found_us=0i load_disk_missing_count=0i load_disk_missing_us=0i entries_missing=0i entry_missing_us=0i failed_to_evict=0i updates_in_mem=0i get_range_us=0i inserts=0i deletes=0i active_threads=1i items=0i keys=0i ms_per_age=416i flush_scan_us=44i flush_update_us=0i flush_grow_us=0i flush_evict_us=0i disk_index_resizes=0i disk_index_max_size=0i disk_index_new_file_us=0i disk_index_resize_us=0i disk_index_flush_file_us=0i disk_index_find_entry_mut_us=0i disk_index_flush_mmap_us=0i disk_data_resizes=0i disk_data_max_size=0i disk_data_new_file_us=0i disk_data_resize_us=0i disk_data_flush_file_us=0i disk_data_flush_mmap_us=0i flush_entries_updated_on_disk=0i flush_entries_evicted_from_mem=0i
[2023-09-18T14:36:31.448632227Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_index estimate_mem_bytes=0i flush_should_evict_us=0i count_in_mem=0i count=0i bg_waiting_percent=99.64503479003906 bg_throttling_wait_percent=80.11323547363281 held_in_mem_slot_list_len=0i held_in_mem_slot_list_cached=0i min_in_bin_mem=0i max_in_bin_mem=0i count_from_bins_mem=0i median_from_bins_mem=0i min_in_bin_disk=0i max_in_bin_disk=0i count_from_bins_disk=0i median_from_bins_disk=0i gets_from_mem=0i get_mem_us=0i gets_missing=0i get_missing_us=0i entries_from_mem=0i entry_mem_us=0i load_disk_found_count=0i load_disk_found_us=0i load_disk_missing_count=0i load_disk_missing_us=0i entries_missing=0i entry_missing_us=0i failed_to_evict=0i updates_in_mem=0i get_range_us=0i inserts=0i deletes=0i active_threads=1i items=0i keys=0i ms_per_age=400i flush_scan_us=49i flush_update_us=0i flush_grow_us=0i flush_evict_us=0i disk_index_resizes=0i disk_index_max_size=0i disk_index_new_file_us=0i disk_index_resize_us=0i disk_index_flush_file_us=0i disk_index_find_entry_mut_us=0i disk_index_flush_mmap_us=0i disk_data_resizes=0i disk_data_max_size=0i disk_data_new_file_us=0i disk_data_resize_us=0i disk_data_flush_file_us=0i disk_data_flush_mmap_us=0i flush_entries_updated_on_disk=0i flush_entries_evicted_from_mem=0i
[2023-09-18T14:36:41.447271663Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_index estimate_mem_bytes=0i flush_should_evict_us=0i count_in_mem=0i count=0i bg_waiting_percent=99.68253326416016 bg_throttling_wait_percent=79.26707458496094 held_in_mem_slot_list_len=0i held_in_mem_slot_list_cached=0i min_in_bin_mem=0i max_in_bin_mem=0i count_from_bins_mem=0i median_from_bins_mem=0i min_in_bin_disk=0i max_in_bin_disk=0i count_from_bins_disk=0i median_from_bins_disk=0i gets_from_mem=0i get_mem_us=0i gets_missing=0i get_missing_us=0i entries_from_mem=0i entry_mem_us=0i load_disk_found_count=0i load_disk_found_us=0i load_disk_missing_count=0i load_disk_missing_us=0i entries_missing=0i entry_missing_us=0i failed_to_evict=0i updates_in_mem=0i get_range_us=0i inserts=0i deletes=0i active_threads=1i items=0i keys=0i ms_per_age=400i flush_scan_us=137i flush_update_us=0i flush_grow_us=0i flush_evict_us=0i disk_index_resizes=0i disk_index_max_size=0i disk_index_new_file_us=0i disk_index_resize_us=0i disk_index_flush_file_us=0i disk_index_find_entry_mut_us=0i disk_index_flush_mmap_us=0i disk_data_resizes=0i disk_data_max_size=0i disk_data_new_file_us=0i disk_data_resize_us=0i disk_data_flush_file_us=0i disk_data_flush_mmap_us=0i flush_entries_updated_on_disk=0i flush_entries_evicted_from_mem=0i
```

I referred to [How to get accounts data from solana snapshot file?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7429/how-to-get-accounts-data-from-solana-snapshot-file) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040650/solana-need-to-export-all-addresses-from-the-blockchain-to-the-db, but I couldn't retrieve the account information as they describe. What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output you provided, you did not let the command run long enough in order to finish. The snapshot(s) must be fully unpacked to allow fetching all of the accounts. This is an expensive process as the snapshots are quite large, so depending on what kind of hardware you're running on, you'll need to give it several minutes to complete.

Also, for future reference, please use code blocks in the future instead of a screen capture of your terminal. You can do so by enclosing your logs/code with three backticks (the ` character) before and after your block

```
Paste log lines here
```